# Define audit columns in base entity class when database column names differ?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a database with common audit columns in each table but with different column names.

**e.g** 
The Person table has the following audit columns,

```
(per_creation_user, per_creation_date, per_update_user, per_update_date),  and the address table has audit columns called  (add_creation_user, add_creation_date, add_update_user, add_update_date).
```

I am trying to map these using JPA annotations and use an event listener class to populate these audit columns automatically whenever they are persisted in the database.

I have a base abstract class containing these audit columns, I could then annotate this with `@MappedSuperclass` and put the entity listener annotation on here too. All neat and tidy, unfortunately the column names differ for each audited entity. I think the only option is to have the audit columns mapped separately on each entity?

Can anybody suggest a better method for doing this?

```
@EntityListeners(BaseDTOEventListener.class)
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseDTO {
    private String creationUser;
    private Date creationDate;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
public class Person extends BaseDTO{
}

@Entity
@Table(name="ADDRESS")
public class Address extends BaseDTO{
}

public class BaseDTOEventListener {
    @PrePersist
    public void onPreInsert(BaseDTO baseDTO){
        baseDTO.setCreationUser("TEST");
        baseDTO.setCreationDate(new Date());

    }
}
```

Comment: You can use Attribute Overrides to redefine the columns in the classes extending from your Mapped Superclass http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Alan for the hint, by specifying column names on each object as below. This worked :)

```
@Entity
@AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name="creationUser", column=@Column(name="PER_CREATION_USER", insertable=true, updatable=false)), 
                 @AttributeOverride(name="creationDate", column=@Column(name="PER_CREATION_DATE" insertable=true, updatable=false})
@Table(name="PERSON")
public class Person extends BaseDTO{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@Embeddable` in combination with `@MappedSuperClass`:

First define the `BaseDTO` interface:

```
@EntityListeners(BaseDTOEventListener.class)
        @MappedSuperclass
        public abstract class BaseDTO {
            public abstract getAuditEmbeddable();

            public void setCreationDate(Date date){
                getAuditEmbeddable().setCreationDate(date);
            }

            public void setCreationUser(String user){
                getAuditEmbeddable().setCreationUser(user);    
            }
        }
```

Then define the embeddable which will hold the audited fields.
User most common column names here.

```
        @Embeddable
        public class AuditEmbeddable{

            @Column(name = "creationUser")
            private String creationUser;

            @Column(name = "creationDate")
            private Date creationDate;

            public String getCreationUser() {
                return creationUser;
            }

            public void setCreationUser(String creationUser) {
                this.creationUser = creationUser;
            }

            public Date getCreationDate() {
                return creationDate;
            }

            public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
                this.creationDate = creationDate;
            }
        }
```

Then you inject an embedded to each of the audited entities, overriding the column names where necessary:

```
        @Entity
        @Table(name="PERSON")
        public class Person extends BaseDTO{

            @Embedded
            private AuditEmbeddable auditEmbeddable;

            public AuditEmbeddable getAuditEmbeddable() {
                return auditEmbeddable;
            }

            public void setAuditEmbeddable(AuditEmbeddable auditEmbeddable) {
                this.auditEmbeddable = auditEmbeddable;
            }
        }

        @Entity
        @Table(name="ADDRESS")
        public class Address extends BaseDTO{

            // lets say here you have custom names for audit fields
            @Embedded
            @AttributeOverrides(
                    @AttributeOverride(name = "creationUser", column = @Column(name = "creationUser123")),
                    @AttributeOverride(name = "creationDate", column = @Column(name = "creationDate123"))
            )
            private AuditEmbeddable auditEmbeddable;

            public AuditEmbeddable getAuditEmbeddable() {
                return auditEmbeddable;
            }

            public void setAuditEmbeddable(AuditEmbeddable auditEmbeddable) {
                this.auditEmbeddable = auditEmbeddable;
            }
        }
```

Finally the listener can stay as you wrote it:

```
        public class BaseDTOEventListener {
            @PrePersist
            public void onPreInsert(BaseDTO baseDTO){
                baseDTO.setCreationUser("TEST");
                baseDTO.setCreationDate(new Date());

            }
        }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, I ended up doing it the way that Alan Hay eluded to in his comment. I will document this in an answer below. Its pretty similar to this but doesn't require the use of an embeddable object. The only thing I noticed which could be an issue with both solutions is if somebody extends the base class without specifying the attributes to override, it creates columns with the same name as the class properties if persisted.

Comment: You define the default column names in the Embeddable. They will be used in case the lack of overrides.

Comment: The problem is there is no default audit column names they all have pre fixes, but maybe by defining some default column names, this would throw an exception rather than hibernate altering the table, and then additional tables could follow this naming convention.

Comment: Correct, i guess that best you can do in that sceario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hibernate envers for the same purpose. You can annotate with @Audited. Apply @NotAudited to the entities you do not want to be

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON")
@Audited
public class Person extends BaseDTO{
}

@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name="ADDRESS")
public class Address extends BaseDTO{
}
```